# How to make exception in for loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop

The code below prints a box with the intergers the user inputs. I need to make it hollow to only display the full length of the first and last line of the box. like width = 5 height = 4

Example Output:

```
00000
0   0
0   0
00000
```

Source:

```
int main () 
{
   int height;
   int width;
   int count;
   int hcount;
   string character;

   cout << "input width" << endl;
   cin >> width;
   cout << "input height" << endl;
   cin >> height;
   cout << "input character" << endl;
   cin >> character;

   for (hcount = 0; hcount < height; hcount++)
   {
       for (count = 0 ; count < width; count++) 
           cout << character;
       cout << endl;
   }
}
```

I do not know how to change the loop condition for the width to make it work.

Comment: Print `character` then print `width - 2` spaces then print another `character`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can test whether you are in the first or last row, and first or last column.

Example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main () 
{
  using namespace std;  // not recommended

  int height;
  int width;
  string character;

  cout << "input width" << endl;
  cin >> width;
  cout << "input height" << endl;
  cin >> height;
  cout << "input character" << endl;
  cin >> character;

  for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
  {
    // Test whether we are in first or last row
    std::string interior_filler = " ";
    if (i == 0 || i == height - 1)
    {
      interior_filler = character;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {
      // Test whether are in first or last column
      if (j == 0 || j == width -1)
      {
        cout << character;
      } else {
        cout << interior_filler;
      }
    }
    // Row is complete.
    cout << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
$ ./a.out 
input width
10 
input height
7
input character
*
OUTPUT
**********
*        *
*        *
*        *
*        *
*        *
**********
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an `if` to the `cout << character` line. If we're not in the first row or column, output a space instead of the character.